# Should I use prepared statements if I am working with already saved data

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli, prepared-statement

Data received from the client are being saved using a prepared statement (query). For example:

```
 if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO table_1 VALUES (?, ?, ?);"))
 {
     $stmt->bind_param(/* data */);
     $stmt->execute();
     // ...
 }
```

If at some point later I will want to work with the client's data do I have to use a prepared statement again? Is there any risk of using just a classic query? For example:

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM table_2 WHERE something = ?;")
{
    $stmt->bind_param("s", /* Selected value from the `table_1` */ );
    $stmt->execute();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: If there is no user interaction, you don't have to use prepare statements.

Comment: In the first example is user interaction ,but in the second one I am just working with already saved data from a client... so saved data are secure enough? And I don't have to use prepared statements / sanitise data? Do I understand it right?

Comment: is someone else beside you able to access data? if yes, you should use prepare statement, otherwise you don't have to.

Comment: If user input forms part of your queries, you should use prepared statements. A malicious SELECT query could be crafted to perform extra actions like dropping tables unless you properly sanitise user input. Prepared statements are the safest way to do that.

Comment: @Anam, your advice is really not enough. It's not uncommon for SQL injection to exploit the fact that we re-use data stored in the database in subsequent queries -- sort of an indirect attack. Just use parameters! There's no good reason not to.

Answer (score 2):

You should *always* use parameterized queries as they ensure the data is properly escaped at the database level. This is something you can handle on your own, but doing so is error prone.

Note that the query has to be properly parameterized. Simply using `prepare` is not necessarily enough.

Consider is you had an apostrophe in a column you were storing to the other table. If it were not properly escaped, you would get an error.

Comment: I agree. You lose absolutely nothing by using parameterized queries, so just always use them, even if you are providing the values. It takes at most one extra line of code per parameter.

Comment: @Mike, it's even easier if you use PDO; no binding necessary, just pass an array to execute().

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should use prepared statements/parameterised queries if your queries can contain any user input (like forming a specifying a WHERE clause from a user search term).

The biggest danger in allowing user input in queries isn't persisting malicious data, it's [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). That can be done on any type of query, so, where you run queries including user input you should always use parameterised prepared statements (or manually escape all user input according to your RDBMS's rules).

Comment: If you use PDO, you can use prepared statements (client-side) even for RDBMS that don't support them.